# Spring boot - Data Source configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data

Am using Spring Boot version 1.2.7 in my project. Planning to use Spring Data JPA and trying to setup Universal connection pool to setup Datasource for mysql JDBC.

Am getting the following error and unable to setup Datasource.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:689)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:969)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:958)
    at mymantri.MymantriApplication.main(MymantriApplication.java:13)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 27 more
```

My pom.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>test</name>
    <description>Test</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>test.TestApplication</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ucp</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.eaio.uuid</groupId>
            <artifactId>uuid</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>Angel.SR3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

TestApplication.java,

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, VelocityAutoConfiguration.class })
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

application-dev.properties,

```
application.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
application.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mymantri
application.datasource.username=root
application.datasource.password=root
application.datasource.initialSize=5
application.datasource.maxPoolSize=5
application.datasource.minPoolSize=5

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

DataSource class,

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "testEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "testTransactionManager", basePackages = { "com.mymantri.web.repository"})
public class ApplicationDataSource {

    /** The Constant LOGGER. */
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(ApplicationDataSource.class);

    /** The Constant TEST_SQL. */
    private static final String TEST_SQL = "select 1 from dual";

    /** The pooled data source. */
    private PoolDataSource pooledDataSource;


    /** The environment. */
    private Environment environment;

    /** The Constant CONNECTION_WAIT_TIMEOUT_SECS. */
    private static final int CONNECTION_WAIT_TIMEOUT_SECS = 300;

    /**
     * Data source.
     * 
     * @return the pool data source
     */
    @Bean(name = "testDataSource")
    @Primary
    public PoolDataSource testDataSource() {

        this.pooledDataSource = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();
        final String databaseDriver = environment
                .getRequiredProperty("application.datasource.driverClassName");
        final String databaseUrl = environment
                .getRequiredProperty("application.datasource.url");
        final String databaseUsername = environment
                .getRequiredProperty("application.datasource.username");
        final String databasePassword = environment
                .getRequiredProperty("application.datasource.password");
        final String initialSize = environment
                .getRequiredProperty("application.datasource.initialSize");
        final String maxPoolSize = environment
                .getRequiredProperty("application.datasource.maxPoolSize");
        final String minPoolSize = environment
                .getRequiredProperty("application.datasource.minPoolSize");

        try {
            pooledDataSource.setConnectionFactoryClassName(databaseDriver);
            pooledDataSource.setURL(databaseUrl);
            pooledDataSource.setUser(databaseUsername);
            pooledDataSource.setPassword(databasePassword);
            pooledDataSource.setInitialPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(initialSize));
            pooledDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(maxPoolSize));
            pooledDataSource.setMinPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(minPoolSize));
            pooledDataSource.setSQLForValidateConnection(TEST_SQL);
            pooledDataSource.setValidateConnectionOnBorrow(Boolean.TRUE);
            pooledDataSource
                    .setConnectionWaitTimeout(CONNECTION_WAIT_TIMEOUT_SECS);
            // pooledDataSource.setConnectionPoolName(poolName);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Unable to parse passed numeric value", e);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error("exception creating data pool", e);
        }

        LOGGER.info("Setting up datasource for user:{} and databaseUrl:{}",
                databaseUsername, databaseUrl);
        return this.pooledDataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "testEntityManagerFactory")
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        lef.setDataSource(myMantriDataSource());
        lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        lef.setPackagesToScan("com.mymantri.web.domain");
        lef.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        lef.setPersistenceUnitName("myMantriPersistenceUnit");
        lef.afterPropertiesSet();
        return lef.getObject();
    }

    @Bean(name = "testTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect",
                "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"); 
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans",
                "true");    
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql","true");

        return properties;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the environment.
     * 
     * @param environment
     *            the new environment
     */
    @Autowired
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {

        this.environment = environment;
    }

}
```

Not sure, what is wrong with this config. Am i missing anything in the SpringBootConfig config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the Application to com.XXXXXX.web package works.

com.XXXXXX.web.domain - for domain classes
com.XXXXXX.web.repository - for repository classes

The default annotation scanning occurs based on the Application class package name.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change data source registration method signature:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
```

BTW, it's not good idea to have local variables in configuration class. You have `environment` and `pooledDataSource`. Remove these class variables and  create them locally in methods + pass them to Spring IoC container via `@Bean` annotation.

I suggest to change your configuration class at least this way:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "testEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "testTransactionManager", basePackages = { "com.mymantri.web.repository"})
public class ApplicationDataSource {

    /** The Constant LOGGER. */
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(ApplicationDataSource.class);

    /** The Constant TEST_SQL. */
    private static final String TEST_SQL = "select 1 from dual";

    /** The Constant CONNECTION_WAIT_TIMEOUT_SECS. */
    private static final int CONNECTION_WAIT_TIMEOUT_SECS = 300;

    /**
     * Data source.
     * 
     * @return the pool data source
     */
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(Environment environment) {

        PoolDataSource pooledDataSource = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();
        final String databaseDriver = environment
                .getRequiredProperty("application.datasource.driverClassName");
        final String databaseUrl = environment
                .getRequiredProperty("application.datasource.url");
        final String databaseUsername = environment
                .getRequiredProperty("application.datasource.username");
        final String databasePassword = environment
                .getRequiredProperty("application.datasource.password");
        final String initialSize = environment
                .getRequiredProperty("application.datasource.initialSize");
        final String maxPoolSize = environment
                .getRequiredProperty("application.datasource.maxPoolSize");
        final String minPoolSize = environment
                .getRequiredProperty("application.datasource.minPoolSize");

        try {
            pooledDataSource.setConnectionFactoryClassName(databaseDriver);
            pooledDataSource.setURL(databaseUrl);
            pooledDataSource.setUser(databaseUsername);
            pooledDataSource.setPassword(databasePassword);
            pooledDataSource.setInitialPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(initialSize));
            pooledDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(maxPoolSize));
            pooledDataSource.setMinPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(minPoolSize));
            pooledDataSource.setSQLForValidateConnection(TEST_SQL);
            pooledDataSource.setValidateConnectionOnBorrow(Boolean.TRUE);
            pooledDataSource
                    .setConnectionWaitTimeout(CONNECTION_WAIT_TIMEOUT_SECS);
            // pooledDataSource.setConnectionPoolName(poolName);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Unable to parse passed numeric value", e);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error("exception creating data pool", e);
        }

        LOGGER.info("Setting up datasource for user:{} and databaseUrl:{}",
                databaseUsername, databaseUrl);
        return pooledDataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        lef.setDataSource(myMantriDataSource());
        lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        lef.setPackagesToScan("com.mymantri.web.domain");
        lef.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        lef.setPersistenceUnitName("myMantriPersistenceUnit");
        lef.afterPropertiesSet();
        return lef.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect",
                "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"); 
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans",
                "true");    
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql","true");

        return properties;
    }

}
```